# Convert Char To Boolean

Tags: c#, casting

In C++ is assumed to be false while all other values are true.  I was under the impression that in C# this concept was the same.

I'm trying to convert a char to a bool.

```
char c = (char)0;
Convert.ToBoolean(c).Dump();
```

It seems like no matter what char I try to convert I always get an error

> Invalid cast from 'Char' to 'Boolean

I understand what I can to to fix this if I write my own custom function, but what I am trying to understand is.

What is the purpose of this method, What Char value converts to Bool?

Comment: You can use this as a byte or Int32 to boolean. But with char or with string you cannot do this. For byte and int, you will get false for only 0 , true for all values other than 0. And you can use this conversion for double or float types too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stated:

> I was under the impression that in C# this concept was the same.

You were mistaken.  It isn't.  The two languages behave differently in that way, and you simply cannot convert a `Char` to a `Boolean`.

The documentation makes it clear that the method always fails:

> Calling this method always throws `InvalidCastException`.

and...

> Return Value
>
> Type: `System.Boolean`
>
> This conversion is not supported. No value is returned.

As evidenced by the source for `Char.ToBoolean()`:

```
[__DynamicallyInvokable]
bool IConvertible.ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
{
    object[] values = new object[] { "Char", "Boolean" };
    throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_FromTo", values));
}
```

As the `Char` class inherits from `IConvertible`, it is required to provide the overload.  But since this conversion is not possible, an exception is always returned.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show how it can be done with *unsafe* keyword (similar to c++). Don't use this..

```
char c = (char)0;
unsafe{
    bool b = *((bool *)&c);
}
```

Comment: Why would you ever do this over just writing `c == 0`?

Comment: @Servy It's just to show how one type can be converted to another *unsafely*

Comment: But the question didn't ask how to convert a `char` to a `bool` unsafely.  The question said that they already knew how to write their own code to convert the value; they were asking about the behavior of `Convert.ToBoolean`.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the purpose of this method...?

From the [.NET 2.0 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff6t8509(v=vs.80).aspx):

> This method is reserved for future use.

Perhaps they were considering implementing it along the lines of C++ but eventually decided not to.

**EDIT - IConvertible is *not* the reason**

There seems to be some confusion about the `char.ToBoolean()` method.

```
((IConvertible)someChar).ToBoolean(...);
```

is a separate issue from `Convert.ToBoolean`. (Why the explicit conversion first - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27096189/939213).) The former *had* to be implemented when `char` was made `IConvertible`. The latter could have simply not been created, so the question of why does that method (`Convert.ToBoolean`) exists seems to be answered only for backwards compatibility + the original intention.

(If I'm the one misunderstanding this - please let me know, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```cpp
Convert.ToBoolean(Convert.ToInt32(charVar.ToString()))
```